# Contacts Gem not importing yahoo contacts in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using contacts-1.2.4 for importing contacts from yahoo and gmail. The issue I am facing is that this gem is working fine on my local setup but on my production environment yahoo contacts importing is not working. It repeatedly gives authentication error. I am using Rails-3.1.1 and ruby-1.9.2 for my local and production setup.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working using - https://github.com/liangzan/contacts

Now importing is working fine on production env as well.

Answer (score 1):

For yahoo and gmail it is better to use https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts since it doesn't require people to enter their username and password.